# Как скрыть объект у одного игрока в photon UNITY2D?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Нужна помощь.
Мне надо включить камеру у того игрока, который вышел из комнаты и включить другую. При этом  у камер есть ограничения (CinemachineConfiner) на определенный полигон.

Код ниже в мультиплеерной игре работает так - показывается камера, которая была включена первой, а другая не показывается.

Очень прошу, помогите, если что-то плохо объяснил - то спросите.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class FrameSwitch : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject activeFrame;

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("mog"))
        {
            activeFrame.SetActive(true);
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("mog"))
        {
            activeFrame.SetActive(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Еще пробовал при спавне игрока привязывать ему префаб камеры, а камере в компоненте Follow изменять на игрока.